# Intuition behind unbiased OLS estimator derivation

Tags: least-squares, expected-value, unbiased-estimator

I was going through the derivation of unbiased OLS estimator

$$E(\hat{\beta_1}) = \beta_1 + (1/SST_x)  \sum_{i=1}^n d_i E(u_i) = \beta_1 + (1/SST_x) \sum_{i=1}^n d_i\cdot 0 = \beta_1$$

My doubt is if $$ d_i = x_i - \bar{x} $$ and assuming Gauss-Markov theorem is true that $x_i$ is independent of $u_i$.

Then how, $$ (1/SST_x) E(\sum_{i=1}^n d_i u_i) = (1/SST_x)  \sum_{i=1}^n d_i E(u_i)  $$

how can we treat $d_i$ as constant and we didn't take expectation of $d_i$. What is the intuition behind this?

Comment: Your equations seem to be for simple linear regression, instead of the more general ordinary least squares method.

Comment: Yes. I just want to understand from what intuition $d_i = x_i - \bar{x}$ is considered constant in this equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this as the expectation being unbiased *conditional* on $x$, in which case the $d_i$ can be considered constants.

(and since the conditional expectation is zero, so will be the unconditional expectation)

---

**The derivation in your question is only correct for *constant* $x$.**

**But it happens to be the same result for *variable* $x$, because the expectation conditional on $x$ is zero independent of it's value. (but for this extra step, from constant to conditional, the derivation is indeed not complete)**

---

See here an intuitive plot how the marginal distribution of $y$ can be considered as a sum of the distributions of $y$ conditional on $x_1$.

[image: example]

The data here has been generated according to some silly/fancy model:

$$\begin{array}{}
 x_1 &\sim& N(\mu = 10, \sigma = 1) \\
y \vert x_1  &\sim & N(\mu = 0, \sigma = 2+ \sin(5x_1))
\end{array}$$

You can consider the distribution of $y$ as a sum of the distributions/components of $y$ conditional on $x$. When each of these components has a mean equal to zero, then the sum of them will also be zero.

```
### settings for layout and computation
set.seed(1)
layout(matrix(1:2,1), widths = c(2,1))
par(mar= c(4,4,2,1), mgp = c(2.5,0.8,0))

### generate data
x <- rnorm(10^4,10,1)
y <- rnorm(10^4,0,2+sin(x*5))

### conditional colouring
col <- hsv(x/14,1,1,0.1)

### scatterplot
plot(x,y, col = col, bg = col, pch = 21, cex = 0.7, ylim = c(-10,10), main = "scatter plot \n", cex.main = 1,
     xlab = expression(x[1]))


### density plots for different conditions x
plot(-100,-100, ylim = c(-10,10), xlim = c(0,220),
     xlab = "", ylab = "", main = "conditional \n distribution", cex.main = 1)

for (xs in seq(7,13,0.4)) {
  sel = ((x>xs-0.2)*(x<xs+0.2))
  h <- hist(y[sel==1], breaks = seq(-15,15,0.4), plot = FALSE)
  lines(h$counts,h$mids, col = hsv(xs/14,1,1,0.5), lwd = 2)
}
```

Comment: how $d_i$ is constant for given x? I know that $\sum_{i=1}^nd_i$ is zero. But here it is $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i u_i$. So, how $E[\sum_{i=1}^n d_i u_i | X]$ makes d_i constant? Is there any proof or explanation that makes $d_i$ constant for given x?

Comment: *how $d_i$ is constant for given $x$?* Because $d_i$ is a function of $x$. If $x$ is constant, then $d_i$ is constant.

Comment: $d_i$ = $x_i - \bar{x} $ where $\bar{x}$ is mean of X. Thus, $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x}) = 0$, all $x_i $ are independent and identically distributed.

Comment: When $x$ is constant, I mean that all $x_i$ are constant. It might be that you consider a case with varying $x_i$, but for a *conditional* expression you can consider the $x_i$ and $d_i$ to be constant. To go from constant $x_i$ to non constant $x_i$ you can use: $$E(a) = \sum_{\forall b} E(a | b) p(b)$$ So if the conditional expressions are zero (for constant x) then so will be the marginal expression (for varying x).

Comment: So the trick for varying x is to compute the expectation of beta for each individual (constant) x, and then get the overall expectation by summing/integrating over all the possible states of x (and weighing their probability). This sum is easy because each conditional term is zero.

Comment: Got it. For varying x, it is like law of iterated expectations. It's just that for a given x, considering $x_i$ and $d_i$ as constant seems less intuitive to me.

Comment: So you are right you can not go from $E(\sum d_i u_i)$ to $E(d_i \sum u_i)$ if the $d_i$ are not constant. Still for not constant $d_i$ or $x_i$ you may still get the same result, but that is only because the conditional expectations are zero. It is not true in general. **Thus, the derivation in your question is only correct for constant $x$, but because the expectation is zero it happens to give the same result as variable $x$ (but this requires an extra derivation step).**

Comment: @MayankMittal, It's just that for a given x, considering xi and di as constant seems less intuitive to me. Imagine a joint distribution of $\hat\beta_1-\beta_1$ and $x = \lbrace x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n$ as a multidimensional cloud. Getting the marginal distribution of $\hat\beta_1-\beta_1$ at once is maybe not so intuitive, because the varying $x$, but could you describe an intersection? For such intersection you describe the distribution/density of $\hat\beta_1-\beta$ while keeping other values *fixed*.

Comment: Interestingly, with the example that I made (in the edit) I realize now that the expectation of the marginal distribution might actually be undefined. For instance take $$\begin{array}{}
 x &\sim& N(\mu = 0, \sigma = 1) \\
y \vert x  &\sim & N(\mu = 0, \sigma = \vert 1/x \vert )
\end{array}$$

then $y$ is a Cauchy distributed variable, which has no defined mean/expectation. Yet, the distribution of $y \vert x$ is defined almost everywhere. So $E(y \vert x)$ needs to be defined everywhere or otherwise it can get tricky.